# move a node from one section of the xml to other using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

As a part of my learning curve of XSLT. I came across the following situation and trying to accomplish it.

I have an xml in the following format.

```
<parent>
  <A> .. </A>
  <T1>  
  <d1>..</d1>
  <d2>..</d2>

 </T1>
 <T1>
   <d1>..</d1>
   <d2>..</d2>
 </T1>
  ...
 <T1>
   <d1>..</d1>
   <d2>..</d2>
 </T1>

   </parent>
```

and I am trying to move the node 'A' to under T1,T1...T1. so that final output looks like this

```
 <parent>  
 <T1> 
   <A> .. </A> 
   <d1>..</d1>
   <d2>..</d2>
 </T1>

 <T1>
   <A> .. </A>
   <d1>..</d1>
   <d2>..</d2>
 </T1>
  ...
 <T1>
   <A> .. </A>
   <d1>..</d1>
   <d2>..</d2>
 </T1>
</parent>
```

Following is the xslt that i have been working with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:DTCC="http://www.informatica.com/B2B/DTCC/NSCC/2014_03">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

 <xsl:variable name="submittingHeader">   
         <xsl:copy-of select="./A/*" /> 
    </xsl:variable> 

<xsl:template match="T1" >
 <xsl:value-of select="$submittingHeader"/>    

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I am trying to move  atleast node A to under T1. Once if i get that then I will put for-each loop over matching template T1.

The output which i see is same the as input xml only. I dont see node 'A' getting moved under 'T1'. I think I am not correctly copying the content of a variable or i am missing something? Any guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you are not doing properly:

- your `submittingHeader` variable is not selecting the `A` node (you should have used `//A`, as the variable is outside any template)
- you are not omitting the original `A` element from the output
- you are trying to copy `A` before copying `T1`

This should produce the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:DTCC="http://www.informatica.com/B2B/DTCC/NSCC/2014_03">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <!-- avoid copying A in its original position -->
    <xsl:template match="A"/>

    <xsl:template match="T1" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- copy A inside the copied T1 -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="../A" />   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```